# How to export a geopandas dataframe to excel

Tags: python, geopandas

Iam writing a simple code and would like to export the content of the GEODATAFRAME to excel.

Please advise what is the simplest way to achieve that.

The code is as follows:

```
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
world.plot()
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.show()
print(world)
```

I have tried the following code without success:

```
xlpath='C:/'
df=pd.DataFrame(eval(world))
export_excel = df.to_excel(xlpath)
```

This is the GEODATAFRAME(table) that i want to export to excel.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works the same as a pandas dataframe - you can just Google how to do that.

In your case

```
import geopandas as gpd
world = gpd.read_file(gpd.datasets.get_path('naturalearth_lowres'))
xlpath='C:/folder1/folder2/filename.xlsx'
world.to_excel(xlpath)    # do not use here export_excel=df.to_excel...
```

Comment: This might be nitpicking, but path must be fully defined and include the file type. For example: xlpath='C:/folder1/folder2/filename.xlsx'