# How to save and load any python variable directly to/from excel?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, shapely

Is there a way to save any type of python variable from a dataframe to excel and then be able to load that variable in python whenever needed.
Take the following image for example, I was working with shapely and following is some data that I saved in an excel, Is it possible to load the circular boundary column into python directly as shapely variables and not strings?

Comment: Is this helpful: [How to export a geopandas dataframe to excel](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58478193/7851470)?

Answer (score 0):

Your column is in a format called Well Known Text, or WKT. You can convert from string to Shapely geometry using [`shapely.wkt.loads()`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.wkt.loads).

First load the Excel as a DataFrame:

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.read_excel('path/to/my/file.xlsx')
```

Next, load the geometry from the string:

```py
from shapely import wkt

df['Circular Boundary'] = df['Circular Boundary'].apply(wkt.loads)
```

If you want to do more work with the geometry, you may wish to transform to a geopandas GeoDataFrame, using your newly-loaded geometry:

```py
import geopandas

gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(df, geometry='Circular Boundary')
```

This is all based on an example in the [geopandas docs](https://geopandas.org/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html?highlight=wkt#from-wkt-format).